# how to have a .pdf page where the user can enter information into the inputs then print

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to make a page that where the user can enter information into the inputs and print from there. an example would be [this website](https://member.societyforscience.org/document.doc?id=33). 
How would you go about doing that.

Comment: you try SOMETHING before asking for help? Stack is not meant as a full design/coding service. You need to show you tried something..... what are your ideas so far, what have you tried, why doesn't it fit your need? I don't want to sound mean or snarky, but this is way too broad and will likely be put on hold. You should try to edit your question to add more meat to it, more context so we can actually help you

Comment: I have tried but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF is designed with editable regions, that the user can then fill in this is uploaded to the web server and accessed through the website this can be done in adobe check this link - http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/acrobat/pdfs/adobe-acrobat-xi-convert-forms-into-fillable-pdf-tutorial_ue.pdf

Comment: thanks a lot. it really helped. now I can add a whole lot more to my website. the link is really helpful too